# write failed transactions to ganache

Tags: solidity, ganache, solidity-0.8.x, ganache-cli

i'm trying to debug a complex transaction in ganache (using mainnet fork). it reverts and i want to debug why exactly.

i cannot use truffle debugger because it wants transaction hash, but i don't have it as transaction is not written in the blockchain, and new block is not generated.
i tried also with enabled blockTime, but still same.
i tried console.log and emit events, but both of them also works only for successful transactions, or at least transactions with hash.

how do i force failed/reverted transaction to store in ganache so i can debug it, or maybe there is other way to see somehow debug prints from my solidity function to trace where it fails.